# joomla footer position

Tags: joomla1.5

joomla 1.5 footer is displaying below left and right panels BUT if length of content panel EXCEEDS both of these, the footer is not being pushed any lower. In other words, the footer will display within content div area if the content is longer than left / right divs.
The obvious possibility is that the div floats are not being cleared but my my css footer id includes:

```
clear: both;
```

My template code for footer is

```
<div id = "footer">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="xhtml" />
     </div>
```

Can anyone spot the error or suggest where to look?

Comment: Can you post a link? It's very difficult to make suggestions based on snippet of code? You might want to look for http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ and apply this to your left and right panels

Comment: Did this help? If so, please accept the answer or provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a link? It's very difficult to make suggestions based on snippet of code? You might want to look for nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack and apply this to your left and right panels

Comment: Thanks for the nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack link. I will try that.
Sorry I can't show you the web-site because I am not publishing the footer on a live site until I can be sure there are no errors displayed. I can add that I have discovered an interesting difference in the way IE8 handles the css footer. It will not read it at all from a style sheet but only if the footer Div is styled on the page (all other positions are read properly from style sheet). However the net result is the same so I guess this is a seperate problem.